How can I uninstall KB2767916 on Windows 11?
I'm trying to remove the update KB2767916 as it is causing issues with my Microsoft Office 2007 installation. I was able to do so on Windows 10 without issues. However, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to uninstall this update on Windows 11.
The update history shows that KB2767916 has been installed, but it does not appear under the "Uninstall updates" option. I ran wusa /uninstall /kb:2767916 in the command prompt with admin privileges, but WUSA says the update is not installed on my computer. Are there any other solutions?

A more interesting question is why are you using Office 2007 in Windows 11?
